# why doesn't python support to kill a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

As we know pthread library supports pthread_kill() to kill a peer thread, but I'm just wondering why doesn't python support this feature? Any answer is helpful, thanks,:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Killing threads isn't really very useful. Indeed, it usually causes trouble.

Killing a thread generall causes (at least) some of the following problems:

- Memory leak
- Other resource leak (file descriptors, etc)
- Deadlock (due to lock which is never unlocked by the killed thread)

Which are undesirable.

Don't do it.

Comment: Just to add a bit of clarification to this answer... Kill the thread by asking it to stop itself, as opposed to immediately terminating it by the parent thread.